# Extract varying amounts information from dataframe/ json

Tags: json, rest, dataframe, data-structures, jupyter

I am beginner in Python (not my profession, just want to learn), so I hope I ask the right question.

I would like to make stats via api. I request the data in json, then I made it to dataframe (`pd.dataframe(ra)`). However, one column ("games") contains more data (especially "Id" e.g: 169707), and I would like to extract those in order to make more request.

I think the best solution would be to make another dataframe, where each column is one another inf from the "games". e.g.: And if there is no ID6 for example then simple it is blank. However, every answer is welcome as I am beginner, so I can imagine there are easier ways.

```
begin_at                 Detailed_stats .... ID1     ID2    
2014-06-15T14:29:01Z     True           .... 169706  169707
```

Here is a little part of data (before dataframe). Additionally some games contains one ID, some contains more IDs, in the example it contains 3.

```
'games': [{'begin_at': '2014-06-15T14:00:00Z',
    'detailed_stats': True,
    'end_at': '2014-06-15T14:29:01Z',
    'finished': True,
    'forfeit': False,
    'id': 169706,
    'length': 1741,
    'match_id': 21658,
    'position': 1,
    'status': 'finished',
    'video_url': None,
    'winner': {'id': 85, 'type': 'Team'},
    'winner_type': 'Team'},
   {'begin_at': '2014-06-15T15:00:00Z',
    'detailed_stats': True,
    'end_at': '2014-06-15T15:40:31Z',
    'finished': True,
    'forfeit': False,
    'id': 169707,
    'length': 2431,
    'match_id': 21658,
    'position': 2,
    'status': 'finished',
    'video_url': None,
    'winner': {'id': 249, 'type': 'Team'},
    'winner_type': 'Team'},
   {'begin_at': '2014-06-15T16:00:00Z',
    'detailed_stats': True,
    'end_at': '2014-06-15T16:35:43Z',
    'finished': True,
    'forfeit': False,
    'id': 169708,
    'length': 2145,
    'match_id': 21658,
    'position': 3,
    'status': 'finished',
    'video_url': None,
    'winner': {'id': 85, 'type': 'Team'},
    'winner_type': 'Team'}],
```

I tried to solve   with  (before made it dataframe) `ra['games'] --> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

And I tried every solution, what I could read on internet, but nothing worked, but I think it should be very easy. Thanks!